# Retaining the textbox value after Page refresh in PHP

Tags: php

How to retain the value of a textbox even after page refresh in php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: Use Database System or Sessions !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202825/how-to-retain-textarea-contents-when-php-page-is-refreshed?rq=1

Comment: crypticous - My textboxvalue is run time... how do i retain the value even after refreshing... I have tried sessions. Its not working for me..

Comment: Do you mean after page refresh only, or after submit ?

Comment: After submit -  Simon_eQ

Comment: Then put this code: `<?php if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST["xxx"])){echo $_POST["xxx"]} ?>` inside the `value=""`  and replace `"xxx"` with the form name

Comment: I used ur code.. Still its not working. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example 1

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['test'];
}
?>    
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['test']) ? $_SESSION['test'] : ''; ?>" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Example 2

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : ''; ?>" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the data in text box after the page submit give it like below example

`<input type="text" name="sample" value="<?php (isset($_POST['sample']))?$_POST['sample']:''; ?>" />`

Comment: its not working..

Here i have a textbox and a button. When i click this button, a dialog will appear which has the submit button. When i click submit, the textbox values are taken and moved to another table using AJAX. and hence the page reloads.. 

After page reloads the value should remain.